# Issue with clip-path on an image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, clipping

I'm trying to apply a clip-path to an image. I want the bottom right corner to be covered by a triangle. I've got this working in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But I can't seem to get it working in Internet Explorer. Despite searching intensively I don't seem to be able to get a definite answer on the issue on how to implement this for IE. Some sources say do it like this (and I see this working in IE11)... Others say it's [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path). Makes me confused. Maybe someone can help me based on the following code sample of the styles and SVG I use. Thanks in advance!

```
    .clip {
        -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 349px 0, 349px 128px, 297px 233px, 0 233px);
        clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");     
    }

    <svg width="349" height="233">
        <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
             <polygon points="0 0, 349 0, 349 128, 297 233, 0 233"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
```

Comment: CanIUse is normally correct.

Comment: Thanks, I know. The link that supposedly had the example also uses a fake image.. I'll remove that. Now, is there another way to approach this?

Comment: Have you thought of doing it all in SVG - which would allow it to work in IE? SVG has a handy <image> element

Answer (score 4):

IE will apply a clip-path to an SVG `<image>` element. It will not, however apply a clip-path to an HTML `<img>` element or a background image or anything other non-SVG element.

Safari and Chrome have the same limitation at the moment FWIW but they support -webkit-clip-path which does work on HTML elements, which is why your example works there.

Firefox supports clip-path on non-SVG elements which is why it works there.